# How to control the speed of urdf model using moveit

Tags: ros, urdf, moveit, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i dynamically vary the speed of urdf robot while it is doing some path planning in rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247887/how-to-control-the-speed-of-urdf-model-using-moveit/) by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After @Stefan's response I wrote up a similar tutorial on this for MoveIt!: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/pull/50/

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2016-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The joint velocity limits can be set in the URDF like [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/taurob_tracker_common/blob/master/taurob_arm_description/urdf/taurob_arm_macros.urdf.xacro.xml#L14). They additionally can be overwritten in the MoveIt [joint_limits.yaml](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_tracker_planning/blob/master/hector_tracker_robot_moveit_config/config/joint_limits.yaml) file. To change the speed on a per motion plan basis, you can set the two scaling factors for velocity and accelerations as described in [MotionPlanRequest.msg](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_msgs/blob/jade-devel/msg/MotionPlanRequest.msg#L37). Spinboxes for setting both of those are also available in the MoveIt! MotionPlanning rviz plugin.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-11-12**:
Is there also a way to limit the TCP-Speed?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-11-12**:
AFAIK no. There are planning constraints: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_msgs/blob/jade-devel/msg/Constraints.msg, but time parametrization happens after planning. Not sure if the ROS Industrial guys do something special in Descartes or the Cartesian Planner plugin.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2016-11-13**:
Descartes enforces joint velocity limits between each Cartesian point, but not end effector speed (is that what TCP stands for... tool control point?).

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-11-13**:
I'm using a UR10 that is limited to 25cm/s by the controller. Now I need to execute a plan as fast as possible. If my planned motion is slowed down by the controller, the motion stops after executing only a first part. Is there a way to work with robot that moves slower than expected?